# How to set title for row in PickerView in Swift 3?

Tags: ios

I need to give title for rows according to array but I don't know how to do this. I'm new to iOS.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    var names: Array<String>?
    var department: Array<String>?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        names = ["Vineeta", "Shubham" ,"Anand", "Vivek", "Akshay", "Harshit", "Vikas", "Prasoon", "Sunil"]
        department = ["iOS","Angular", ".Net", "iOS","iOS", ".Net", "Android","Android", "Angular"]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 9
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0 {
            [names o]
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You provided a lot of code so it looks like you’ve tried something, and the part of the code that matters is blank.  You’re just asking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Thank you for you feedback @Abizem, next time i'll keep that in mind before asking any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code -

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    if component == 0
    {
        return names?.count
    }
    else
    {
        return department?.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    if component == 0
    {
        return names?[row]
    }
    else
    {
        return department?[row]
    }
}
```

Comment: @abhishek  you have to use switch case in place of if condition for better performance.

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks buddy, you just solved my problem instead of just commenting some un-required suggestions.

Comment: @VivekTyagi You're welcome buddy! Please vote my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

don't forget UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource

@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerData = ["X","Y"]
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self

    }


    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return pickerData.count
        }
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return pickerData[row]
        }
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
           let selectedText = pickerData[row]
        }
```